# Jenkins job status - Customize color / status of job

Tags: jenkins, icons, jenkins-plugins, status, hudson-plugins

Is there a way to customize the status of a Jenkins job to use different icons or colors other than just simple blue/green ball icons.

Something like what we see in cloudbees Jenkins instance or similar.

https://jenkins.ci.cloudbees.com/

For more (if possible), I'd like an option to have the ball status for a queued build job to change to a different color or icon. For example, a clock/stop-watch or an hour glass, or maybe change the color to a clear white sphere. This would help **new users** avoid accidentally launching a queued build multiple times expecting the job status icon to start flashing and etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following plugins can help to achieve what I'm looking for (to some degree).

1. https://plugins.jenkins.io/modernstatus/
   (I'll poke around in this plugin to see if I can change this **"Modern Status**" plugin -- to change the icon(s) for ex: change icon to a pending/hour glass icon if a build is sitting in "queue" and etc).
2. https://github.com/kralq/distinguishable-gray-balls-plugin
3. https://plugins.jenkins.io/custom-job-icon/ (as Mike mentioned in the other reply) - to classify a job type (using various icons).

Comment: I knew of Green Balls, but avoided it because I don't want to make people tell me they can't differentiate red and green. The Modern Status plugin is almost exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

The answer seems to be in their code for [BallColor.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/BallColor.java).

At the time of this writing, here are all the possible values:

```
RED("red",Messages._BallColor_Failed(), ColorPalette.RED),
RED_ANIME("red_anime",Messages._BallColor_InProgress(), ColorPalette.RED),
YELLOW("yellow",Messages._BallColor_Unstable(), ColorPalette.YELLOW),
YELLOW_ANIME("yellow_anime",Messages._BallColor_InProgress(), ColorPalette.YELLOW),
BLUE("blue",Messages._BallColor_Success(), ColorPalette.BLUE),
BLUE_ANIME("blue_anime",Messages._BallColor_InProgress(), ColorPalette.BLUE),
GREY("grey",Messages._BallColor_Pending(), ColorPalette.GREY),
GREY_ANIME("grey_anime",Messages._BallColor_InProgress(), ColorPalette.GREY),
DISABLED("disabled",Messages._BallColor_Disabled(), ColorPalette.GREY),
DISABLED_ANIME("disabled_anime",Messages._BallColor_InProgress(), ColorPalette.GREY),
ABORTED("aborted",Messages._BallColor_Aborted(), ColorPalette.GREY),
ABORTED_ANIME("aborted_anime",Messages._BallColor_InProgress(), ColorPalette.GREY),
NOTBUILT("nobuilt",Messages._BallColor_NotBuilt(), ColorPalette.GREY),
NOTBUILT_ANIME("nobuilt_anime",Messages._BallColor_InProgress(), ColorPalette.GREY),
```

I was pointed to the answer from [here](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/jenkins-API-Where-can-I-find-a-definition-of-all-the-possible-values-for-the-quot-color-quot-variabl-td3457993.html).

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

With coding it's possible. And then there's also the [Custom Job Icon Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/custom-job-icon/).

**Long answer:**

I dealt with the Greenballs plugin changing the testresult trend chart to an ugly green. Thus I [forked](https://github.com/bahrmichael/greenballs-plugin) it and changed the color value.

In the project there were [greenball icons](https://github.com/bahrmichael/greenballs-plugin/tree/master/src/main/webapp). With some additional logic you may specify the icon being displayed depending on the status.

Note that this was not tested with Hudson, but only Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I'll try that Custom Job Icon plugin. One of my colleague also found similar, I'll share.

Comment: Actually this plugin is just putting an icon to represent the TYPE of a job (i.e. for a build job, I can give icon O, for a deploy job I can give icon Y and report/etc job I can give another icon X etc). I'm also looking at the custom work you did (greenballs icons) link you provided (in Github). I'll play around with it. The Custom job plugin doesn't change the blue/green balls status icons (but allows us to visually represent/classify various types of jobs).